# New maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I am using Eclipse Juno.

---

I created a new simple maven project and it is in a SVN repository. However, when I checked in that project, none of the `Maven Dependencies` jar files got included. In fact, The `Maven Dependencies` folder is not even there. I am able to see that folder in my local machine but not in the repository and I am not sure why? I am assuming my project didn't get translated into a maven project when it got checked into the SVN repository?

Comment: Why should one check in these dependencies? Your dependencies are listed in you pom file and either available in your local cache or they will be downloated. They don't belong into the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependencies will be listed in your pom.xml file and the jar files will be automatically downloaded when someone checkout the project and compiles it. Actual jar files needn't be checked in to svn repository, it will just increase the project download size.

Comment: Yea, but when I check them out it doesn't automatically download the jar files needed to run my project and I am not sure why?

Comment: After checking out you have to compile in order to download the jar files

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)

Apache Subversion (often abbreviated SVN, after its command name svn) is a software versioning and revision control system distributed as open source under the Apache License. **Software developers use Subversion to maintain current and historical versions of files such as source code, web pages, and documentation()**.

Simply SVN used to maintain source code of project files in a centralized system. Where as maven is a project builder which help to compile the project and package into war or jar or ear.

As the svn job is only to maintain source code of your project it only collects the source files from your project but not the dependencies.

Comment: But when i check out the project it doesn't automatically load the maven dependency jars which needed to run my project.

Comment: @robben Make sure it has downloaded the pom.xml when you check out the project. If it's not downloading the dependencies try update the maven project.